# Phpdocumenter fatal error: Call to a member function getMethods() on a non-object?

Tags: php, symfony, phpdoc

I'm using phpdocumentor to do php code sniffing. This has been running flawlessly for ages, but suddenly I get a fatal error when it tries to "Transform analyzed project into artifacts:

```
Transform analyzed project into artifacts                          .. PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMethods() on a non-object in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Descriptor/ClassDescriptor.php on line 176
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpdoc:0
PHP   2. phpDocumentor\Application->run() /usr/bin/phpdoc:29
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Application.php:425
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:895
PHP   7. phpDocumentor\Command\Project\RunCommand->execute() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
PHP   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Command/Project/RunCommand.php:269
PHP   9. phpDocumentor\Transformer\Command\Project\TransformCommand->execute() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
etc..
etc..
```

I checked out line 176 in the ClassDescriptor.php file, which reads:

```
175         foreach($this->getUsedTraits() as $trait) {
176             $inheritedMethods = $inheritedMethods->merge(clone $trait->getMethods());
177         }
```

And here I'm kinda stuck. I wouldn't know why there would suddenly be a mistake in phpdocumentor, but I also don't know what else it could be.

Does anybody have any idea how I can solve this? Any debugging tips welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in 2.5.0, turns out all I needed was an upgrade. It was resolved in 2.6.1.

Make sure you delete any cache directories in your target phpdoc directory before running the new version.

(I upgraded it with `sudo peardev upgrade-all` btw)